# How to move data to a @helper in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I'm trying to figure out how I can move my 'years' calculation to a @helper in MVC.

I'd like to move

> var years = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year - 99, 100).Reverse();

One thing I'm not sure about is how to move the code that sets the view model 'Years', which is a

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
```

to the @helper, or do I need to?

Here is my action method inside my controller.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        var years = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year - 99, 100).Reverse();
        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        Student student = studentRepository.Find(userId);

        if (student == null)
        {
            var emptyViewModel = new EditStudentViewModel
            {
                Years = years.Select(c => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = c.ToString(),
                    Value = c.ToString(),
                    Selected = (c == 0)
                }),
                AspNetUserRefId = userId,
                StudentImageResult = new FileContentResult(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Images/no_image.jpg"))), "image/jpeg")
            };
            return View(emptyViewModel);
        }

        var studentViewModel = new EditStudentViewModel
        {
            CatchPhrase = student.CatchPhrase,
            SelectedYearId = student.StartedPracticing,
            Years = years.Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = c.ToString(),
                Value = c.ToString(),
                Selected = (c == student.StartedPracticing)
            }),
            Location = student.Location,
            Education = student.Education,
            Work = student.Work,
            WhyIPractice = student.WhyIPractice,
            Inspirations = student.Inspirations,
            AspNetUserRefId = student.AspNetUserRefId,
            StudentId = student.StudentId,
            StudentImageResult = new FileContentResult(student.StudentImage.Image, "image/jpeg")
        };

        return View(studentViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want/need to do that? Your creating a `SelectList` from the values for use in @Html.DropDownListFor()` which should be done on the controller, not the view (and can be simply `Years = new SelectList(years),`

Comment: it was a suggestion from another post I made. I guess the idea was to take it out of the controller because it shouldn't be there? and then to put it into a helper because it was being performed more then once.

Comment: hi Stephen, do you know anyone who could help me with a project I'm working on? I would pay/hr. I need help with javascript and ajax stuff.

Comment: I am aware of the question (I made some comments myself ) It should be in the controller, but in a private method because it will be called multiple times - in the Create and Edit GET methods, and again in the POST methods if you need to return the view - `private void ConfigureViewModel(EditTeacherViewModel model) { var years = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year - 99, 100).Reverse();  model.Years = Years = new SelectList(years); }` then in each method, after initializing the model, `ConfigureViewModel(model);`